# Loop through each worksheet to get cell values to transfer to another worksheet, which lists all obtained values?

Tags: excel, vba

**Additional details:**

I have one workbook. There are several worksheets named 'Test XXX', all formatted the same. I have one worksheet named 'Table'. The goal is to loop through each Test worksheets and get a specific cell value (e.g. "B2"). The Table worksheet will list each B2 value in a table format (i.e. one row to one Test sheet value).

**Code so far:**

```
Sub loopsheets()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name Like "Test*" Then

Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: seeking guidance on a best solution for the above goal / question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really sure where your problem lies, but you can do it like so.

```
Sub loopsheets()

Dim ws As Worksheet, n As Long

For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name Like "Test*" Then
        n = n + 1
        Worksheets("Table").Cells(n, 1).Value = ws.Range("B2").Value
    End If
Next ws

End Sub
```